# My tranny doesn't work in D but 1st 2nd and reverse are fine how fast can I drive in 2nd gear I have a clss A motorhome

Tags: transmission

My tranny doesn't work in D but 1st 2nd and reverse are fine how fast can I drive in 2nd gear I have a class A motorhome with a 460 ford engine

Comment: Are you saying it won’t pull away in ‘D’, but it will in ‘1’?

Comment: How fast does it normally drive in 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an exact number, but typically 2nd gear is going to get you to about 30mph. Pushing faster than that in 2nd for long distances could potentially damage your engine.

You may have a transmission problem or an issue with your gear change linkage, neither of which you are likely to be able to look into yourself. One thing you could and should check is the transmission fluid level, if it is low fill it up and see if that gets it working again, then monitor how quickly you lose it. If it's a slow leak you may be able to live with it, although I'd still get it checked out.

Comment: I would limit RPM to 3000 until the transmission is fixed.

Comment: I've never seen a motor home with a RPM gauge @blacksmith37.